# sugarcrm - search logic for the leads module

Tags: sugarcrm

I have to create a new role say "master agent". There will be some users under him. This info I will be saving in a database table. When this master agent logs in, I should show only those leads that are assigned to users under him.

When I log in as admin, I am seeing all leads.
When I log in as a user, I am seeing only those leads that are assigned to this specific user.

I want to manipulate the search logic such that I see all the leads that are assigned to users under the `master agent`.

I have been analyzing and looked at the function `create_new_list_query()` in `LeadsInListView` file and the same function also at `data/SugarBean.php` which is responsible for the search functionality. The function is quite confusing of how it performs the search logic.

Please help in manipulating the search logic to include the new role.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

you could customize the Leads' `ListView` by adding the following File to:

```
<SUGAR_PATH>/custom/modules/Leads/view/view.list.php
```

(If this Directory does not exist, create it, also create the `view.list.php` File)

and add the following Code

```
<?php

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.list.php');

class LeadsViewList extends ViewList {

    function listViewProcess() {
        global $current_user;
        $uId = $current_user->id;
        $this->processSearchForm();
        // remove this condition, if your Admin should not see all Leads..
        if(!$current_user->is_admin) {
            // Select From Leads and make a inner join on Users Table to get all users, which reports to
            // if you have the Relationship between your master_agent and his worker in another table, join this..
            $this->params['custom_from'] = ' inner join (select id from users u where u.reports_to_id = "'.$uId.'") as p ';
            $this->params['custom_where'] = ' AND p.id = leads.assigned_user_id ';
        }

        if (empty($_REQUEST['search_form_only']) || $_REQUEST['search_form_only'] == false) {
            $this->lv->setup($this->seed, 'include/ListView/ListViewGeneric.tpl', $this->where, $this->params);
            $savedSearchName = empty($_REQUEST['saved_search_select_name']) ? '' : (' - ' . $_REQUEST['saved_search_select_name']);
            echo $this->lv->display();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Now you can log in with your Master_Agent Account and have a look at the Leads of all your Worker. But notice, now the Leads' ListView is customized so, that only the Records of the Workers of your Master_Agent will be displayed. If you also want to show the Master_Agents' Leads, extend the custom_where clause like this:

```
$this->params['custom_where'] = ' AND p.id = leads.assigned_user_id OR assigned_user_id = "'.$uId.'" ';
```

I hope this will help you, to solve your task..

Patrick